# Create wallet in tron network and send all balances to an address

Tags: node.js, blockchain, tron, tronweb

I have a lot of tron wallets created with **tronWeb**, I need to listen to all of wallets for deposit transaction and send balance amount to some addresses.

how can i handle it?

Is there a way to create wallet with my contract?
Is there a way to trigger wallet to send the amount when deposit transaction happens?
I don't want to listen all latest blocks, just listen to my contract blocks

Comment: Have you found any solution?